# If a function's integral over any Borel set is $0$, it must be 0 - why?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In many proofs concerning complete statistics, the following claim is used in my textbook

> If $\int_A g(x) d\mu(x) = 0$ for any Borel set $A$, then $g(x) = 0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere

Though it's never proven nor given any justification. I'm hoping someone can give me a proper  explaination of why this is?

My intuitive thought was that this implies

$$\int_A g^+ d\mu = \int_A g^- d\mu$$

On any Borel set $A$, and if we consider a sequence of Borel sets approaching any singleton $\{ a \}$ we can understand why $g^+(a) = g^-(a) = g(a) = 0$. But this is not a formal argument and seems poorly worded on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $g$ is not $0$ almost everywhere. Then the Borel measurable set $\{x : g(x)\neq 0\}$ has positive measure. It follows that either $A=\{x : g(x)>0\}$ or $B=\{x : g(x)<0\}$ have positive measure. Suppose that $\mu(A)>0$.

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $A_n=\{x : \frac{1}{n}<g(x)\}$. Note that all of these sets are Borel measurable. Moreover they are increasing and satisfy that $\cup_n A_n =A$. By continuity of measures it follows that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)=A,
$$
where if $\mu(A)=\infty$ the sequence simply goes to infinity.

In any case there exists $n$ such that $\mu(A_n)>0$. Let $\frac{1}{n}$ denote the constant function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{n}$ and recall that $\frac{1}{n}<g(x)$ for values of $x\in A_n$. Hence, by monotonicity of the integral,
$$
0<\frac{\mu(A_n)}{n}=\int_{A_n} \frac{1}{n} \,d\mu \leq \int_{A_n} g \,d\mu.
$$

If $\mu(A)=0$ then do the above to the function $-g$ to conclude that, for some Borel measurable set $A_n$, 
$$
\int_{A_n} -g \, d\mu = - \int_{A_n} g \neq 0, 
$$
so 
$$
\int_{A_n} g \, d\mu \neq 0. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can first prove it true for nonnegative $g$, i.e., in this case, show that any set $\{x: g(x) > c\}$ must have measure zero.

Once you understand this then prove your result by taking $A$ first to be the positive set of $g$, and then the negative set of $g$.